# excel 2007 - calculate z-scores over a range of cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, statistics

so i put together this big spreadsheet with normal excel functions that works great, but i want to speed it up and make the file size smaller by using vba and pasting static values as opposed to referenced values that are slowing performance (the workbook is about 20 mb right now and will continue to grow)

so i know what i would like to get done but i am struggling to put it in a concise expression as my VBA experience is still in its infancy, so any help would be appreciated.

z-score = (number - average of all numbers) / (stdev of all numbers)

Worksheets("relay").Value("c32") contains the average of all numbers
Worksheets("relay").Value("c33") contains the stdev of all numbers

what i would like to do, is in the column worksheets("Hitterscalc").range("cb:cb"), calcuate the z-score with the corresponding value found in worksheets("Hitterscalc").range("J:J") for all rows in that column where its corresponding A column cell does not equal "", and its corresponding AB column equals 1

does anybody have any ideas on a concise statement for this? i can get it roughly done cell by cell but when i start putting in loops to run through all the columns it all falls apart in my code, and in my head unfortunately.

thank you for your time

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("hitterscalc").Range("cb2").FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=IF(OR(RC[-79]="""",RC[-52]<>1,Settings!R4C[-74]<>""yes""),"""",(RC[-70]-relay!R32C[-77])/relay!R33C[-77])" 
Sheets("HittersCalc").Select 
Range("CB2").Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("CB2:CB701") Range("CB2:CB701").Select Columns("CB:CB").Select 
Selection.Copy 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Do it all with formulas. Once you have that then redo it with formulas using the macro recorder just for the first row, then get it to autofill down and finally copy and paste values. Turn off the macro recorder and have a look at the code. It will give you an excellent starting point. You may be interested in using Range(..).End(xlDown) to work out how far down you need to autofill

Comment: is there a way to clean this up further?

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("hitterscalc").Range("cb2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(RC[-79]="""",RC[-52]<>1,Settings!R4C[-74]<>""yes""),"""",(RC[-70]-relay!R32C[-77])/relay!R33C[-77])"
    Sheets("HittersCalc").Select
    Range("CB2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("CB2:CB701")
    Range("CB2:CB701").Select
    Columns("CB:CB").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: Rather add code like that to your answer than putting it all in the comments as it's very difficult to read otherwise. I've already edited it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be equivalent to your code:

```
Worksheets("hitterscalc").Range("cb2").FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=IF(OR(RC[-79]="""",RC[-52]<>1,Settings!R4C[-74]<>""yes""),"""",(RC[-70]-relay!R32C[-77])/relay!R33C[-77])" 

'NOTE: Here I am assumimg that there is a column (I've gone with 
'column A but you should change it to whatever is appropriate) that has data
'as far down as you plan on autofilling the columns. So we use that to find how
'far down to autofill rather than hard coding it to 701 as in your code (this is
'the same as when you push ctrl + down in excel)
dim lastRow as int
lastRow = Sheets("HittersCalc").Range("A2").End(xlDown).row

Sheets("HittersCalc").Range("CB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("CB2:CB" & lastRow) 

'A cleaner way to copy and paste by value that doesn't involve the clipboard
Range("CB:CB").Value = Range("CB:CB").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this is old but I was recently looking for a similar solution. I ended up creating my own. I'd prefer a versatile function I could use anytime / anywhere. And if you Don't want the z score calculated then you could use the function inside a nested IF statement.

```
Function zscore(i As Double, rng As Range)
zscore = (i - Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)) / Application.WorksheetFunction.stdev(rng) 
End Function
```

and then a nested if could be something like:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1)>0,IF(AB1=1,IF(C1=J1,zscore(C1,$C$1:$C$6),""),""),"")
```

This gives you a zscore where-ever and whenever you need it, when you want it, without having to make any calculations. If this kind of thing comes up regularly, you could broaden the function for the user to pass more cells to the function (for values in A, AB and J, or any they like), rather than be constrained to a specific subroutine.